# 500 Internal Server Error Appear in every two minutes

Tags: php, internal-server-error

I am working on the script which is getting data from one of the website in the form of rss feed (XML) using curl and i am saving that data into database but the issue is after every 2 minutes the 500 Internal Server Error page appear..
Note: script is only running and saving data into database its not returning or not echo any thing.

Comment: that means the script times out at the second minute - try increasing max execution time in ini :)

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: The error_log may also provide some useful information.

Comment: @aynber the issue is there is no error in the script because the script is terminating at fixed 120th second..
And saving of data depend on the speed of internet some time it save 10 records and sometime 15 and sometime 5 or 6

Comment: @RichGoldMD there is nothing in error log

Comment: Have you tried `set_time_limit(0);` (or use some reasonable limit in seconds so it doesn't run forever). If this is a command-line script that is a reasonable approach.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs i had checked that.. 
is it possible that because we are not returning anything the script thought that something went wrong ?

Comment: @MoizArif nah, if it returns nothing, then it returns nothing with no error - my reason for timing was because it takes X minutes to get to 500 - it might not be timeout, but takes X minutes to get to a certain line in the script. Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);` to the top if the script - might show errors :)

Comment: If this is a utility script that is not generating web output you could try the set_time_limit(0) as well as running it from the command line. In a web server you have the PHP processor and also the web server to consider in terms of limits, we may not be relevant. The errors could also come from the web server.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs It does not work :( :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the solution
Its was happening because when we are running the script on the browser than it check that whether the script is returning something or not it was checking for 2 minutes after 2 minutes it give 500 internal server error...

But if we will run that script on crone than its working fine and running till end.